# UISearchBar not firing

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I put my UISearchController's search bar on navigation bar's titleView. But when I tap to search, UISearchBar does not respond. What can be the cause ?

```
        let tvController:UITableViewController = UITableViewController()
        tvController.tableView.delegate = self
        tvController.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: tvController)
        self.searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController!.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
        self.searchController!.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController!.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
        self.searchController!.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Prominent
        self.searchController!.delegate = self
        self.searchController!.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.searchController!.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController!.searchBar
```

Comment: Have you add `UISearchBarDelegate` to your UIViewController Definition?

Comment: Yes I added UISearchBarDelegate

Answer (score 0):

This might help

Replace

```
self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: tvController)
```

With

```
self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```